# Restart BehaviorSubject after an error

Tags: java, android, rx-java, behaviorsubject

Wanted behavior:

```
subject = BehaviorSubject.create(1);
subject.subscribe(number -> print(number), error -> print(error));

subject.onNext(2);
subject.onNext(3);
subject.onError(new RuntimeException("I'm an error"));
subject.onNext(4);
subject.onNext(5);
```

With this output:

```
1
2
3
I'm an error
4
5
```

My problem is that `onNext` after `onError` isn't working (and this is intended, following `RxJava` rules), but I'll need subject to be resilient to errors, while also passing them down the stream (to show the user some feedback).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `onError` and `onComplete` to be disregarded there is the [RxRelay](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay) library.

Description:

> Subjects are useful to bridge the gap between non-Rx APIs. However, they are stateful in a damaging way: when they receive an onComplete or onError they no longer become usable for moving data. This is the observable contract and sometimes it is the desired behavior. Most times it is not.
>
> Relays are simply Subjects without the aforementioned property. They allow you to bridge non-Rx APIs into Rx easily, and without the worry of accidentally triggering a terminal state.

Comment: Ok, it solves one problem: resilience.  
I still need a way to pass the error to the ui. With BehaviorSubject I just call .onError(error) and the ui receives the error. With BehaviorRelay I can't find find a way to do it.

Comment: @DavidCorsalini I dont think you'll find any implementation that just passes through onError(), mostly since the specification says that its a terminal event for anything downstream. Perhaps create a wrapper class to represent messages and errors as a single object and just use just onNext

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .onErrorReturn() just before subscription

Comment: With .onErrorReturn() I can return a value. If the value changes after an error (this is my case) I won't see these changes. Also, I won't receive errors, because they are overriden by this method.

.onErrorReturnNext() return another Observable to which I'm not subscribed, so I won't receive his nexts.